# Apache Phoenix Installation not done properly

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

We are trying to install **Phoenix 4.4.0** on **HBase 1.0.0-cdh5.4.4** (CDH5.5.5 four nodes cluster) via this installation document:  [Phoenix installation](http://crazyadmins.com/install-and-configure-apache-phoenix-on-cloudera-hadoop-cdh5/)

Based on that we copied our phoenix-server-4.4.0-HBase-1.0.jar to hbase libs on each region server and master server, so that, on each **/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.4.4-1.cdh5.4.4.p0.4/lib/hbase/lib** folder in the master and three region servers.

After that we reboot the HBase service via Cloudera Manager.

Everything seems to be ok, but when we are trying to access to phoenix shell via **./sqlline.py localhost** command, we get a Zookeeper error in that way:

**15/09/09 14:20:51 WARN client.ZooKeeperRegistry: Can't retrieve clusterId from Zookeeper
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /hbase/hbaseid**

So we are not sure that the installation is properly done. Is necessary any further configuration?

We are not even sure wether we are using the sqlline command properly.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is possible that zookeeper.znode.clusterId variable is not set? I mean, following the error in the stack trace, I can see that when                               clusterIdZNode = ZKUtil.joinZNode(baseZNode,
        conf.get("zookeeper.znode.clusterId", "hbaseid"));     is always returning hbaseid by default.  Is necessary to set this zookeeper.znode.clusterId property anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling the 4 nodes cluster on AWS, phoenix is now working properly.
It's a pitty that we don't know exactly what was really happening, but we think that after several changes in our config, we broke something that made phoenix impossible to work.

One thing to take into consideration is that sqllline command has to be executed with an ip that is in the zookeeper quorum, and this is something we were doing wrong, since we were trying to run it from the namenode, and it wasn't in the zookeeper quorum.Once we run sqlline.py from a datanode, everything is working fine.

Btw, the installation guide that we finally followed is [Phoenix Installation](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/developers/home/cloudera-labs/apache-phoenix/install-apache-phoenix-cloudera-labs.pdf)